# Connection closed before receiving a handshake response in websocket-node

Tags: node.js, websocket

I try to establish a websocket connection and i get the above error.
also if i use HTTP connection i get error as : EMPTY_REPONSE
can anybody please help me on this?

Comment: provide more information like how are you connecting.

Comment: hey i got the answer.... you just have to check the Bypass Proxy For Local Server in your internet options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Was resolved with the [ReconnectingWebSocket](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket) by joewalnes.